# How to pass set values to a piechart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, textbox

I attempted to make a pie chart from scratch and it worked.

The problem is it looks rubbish as the graphics are terrible :(

I've decided to use the Winforms chart maker, but setting the source seems to be problematic.
I can't seem to choose to pass values from textboxes, it seems to want only values from a data source.  I have 4 text boxes texbox1 etc.  values are given by user.

How do I create a chart using values from a text box?

So far MSDN and Google have provided no answers only more questions.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some actual code how you try to set your DataSource!

Comment: Also which version of NET are you using?

Comment: ok .net 4 and too answer the code question. i dont have any, i use visual studios wizard to create one, but as i said it only asks for datasource like objects tables from sql etc, i dont need that atm all i need is to pass it 4 values from 4 textboxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops been a while, answer was to use dev-express external ip and add the table to the series source